# halting pdf.js page rendering

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

I have used pdf.js to create a simple pdf viewer that has 2 pages side by side with next,previous buttons and some other features. I used the helloworld example available with the pdf.js repo as the viewer.js file was too complicated for a noob like me. However when I click the previous/next button several times pdf.js renders all the pages instead of the expected last page. It creates a mess. The following example by pdf.js have the same problem. 
http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-prevnext-v2/1/edit (link seems to work in firefox only.)

I want to know what are the ways to make pdf.js render only the last page reached by next/previous buttons. pdf.js api did not help me much. Hope I will get some guidance here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, I might have a solution. 
When I clicked too fast on the buttons previous or next, the canvas had not the time to refresh, and two (or more) pages where drawn, it was unreadable.

To solve the problem, I use the following code :

```
var stop = false;
function goPrevious() {
    if (pageNum > 1 && !stop)
    {
        stop = true;
        pageNum--;
        renderPage(pageNum);
    }
}

function goNext() {
    if (pageNum < pdfDoc.numPages && !stop)
    {
        stop = true;
        pageNum++;
        renderPage(pageNum);
    }
}
```

I have also modified the render function in the pdf.js file :

```
 render: function PDFPageProxy_render(params) {
      this.renderInProgress = true;

      var promise = new Promise();
      var stats = this.stats;
      stats.time('Overall');
      // If there is no displayReadyPromise yet, then the operatorList was never
      // requested before. Make the request and create the promise.
      if (!this.displayReadyPromise) {
        this.displayReadyPromise = new Promise();
        this.destroyed = false;

        this.stats.time('Page Request');
        this.transport.messageHandler.send('RenderPageRequest', {
          pageIndex: this.pageNumber - 1
        });
      }

      var self = this;
      function complete(error) {
        self.renderInProgress = false;
        stop = false;
        if (self.destroyed || self.cleanupAfterRender) {
          delete self.displayReadyPromise;
          delete self.operatorList;
          self.objs.clear();
        }

        if (error)
          promise.reject(error);
        else
          promise.resolve();
      }
      var continueCallback = params.continueCallback;
//etc.
```

(in my pdf.js file, this is between lines 2563 and 2596).

As a result, no new page will be drawn until the previous page was entirely drawn, even if you click very very fast on the previous/next buttons !

An other solution could be to cancel the previous drawing :

```
function renderPage(num) {


pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {

        // canvas resize
        viewport = page.getViewport(ratio);
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;


        // draw the page into the canvas
        var pageTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
        timestamp = pageTimestamp;
        var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: ctx,
                viewport: viewport,
                continueCallback: function(cont) {
                    if(timestamp != pageTimestamp) {
                        return;
                    }
                    cont();
                }
        };
        page.render(renderContext);


        // update page numbers
        document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
        document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;
    });
}
```

I hope it will help you, and sorry for my english ;)
Have a nice day

Comment: I have tried this and it seemed to work better than before, however I still face the issue while clicking too fast.I do not know if you are facing it too. I wish I could disable the buttons until the canvas was loaded fully, I tried using window.onload(), did not work as canvas is taking longer time to load. The complete viewer.html by pdf.js has the halting functionality, can not figure out how they did it though.

Comment: I have only tried your 1st solution, let me check out the 2nd one. Thanks a lot for your effort and your english is great. :)

Comment: I tried cancelling the previous drawing, however timestamp = pageTimestamp; was giving an error timestamp being undefined, so I changed code to var timestamp = pageTimestamp; and now it never gets inside the if(timestamp != pageTimestamp) condition as they are always equal. What am I doing wrong ? Thanks again in advance. :)

Comment: Concerning the first solution, even if I click very very fast, it is ok and only one page is drawn.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem and solve it easier.
The `render()` method returns a `renderTask` object which look like this:

```
renderTask: {
    internarRenedrTask: {...},
    promise: {...}
}
```

The prototype of `renderTask.internalRenderTask` has `cancel()` method which can halt rendering.
So just remember `renderTask.internalRenderTask` object and call `cancel()` if needed:

```
render: function() {
    if (this.renderTask) {
        this.renderTask.cancel();
    }

    // some code here

    this.renderTask = page.render(...).internalRenderTask;
}
```

Comment: 2015: `page.render(...)` is now returning a `renderTask` that has `cancel` method. --> `this.renderTask = page.render(...);`.

Comment: @NinhPham could you provide more info on how to access this method, please? Or is it still relevant in 2019?

Comment: @Jansindl3r, it's still available. https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/RenderTask.html.

Comment: @Jansindl3r, take a look on the [examples](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/), you will see `page.render(..)` and how to access the `renderTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the second solution, you have to create the variable `timestamp` outside the function, for example at the beginning of the file. If you declare `timestamp` inside the function, the variable exists only during the execution of the function and it can't work. S you can do the following :

```
var timestamp;
function renderPage(num) {


pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {

        // canvas resize
        viewport = page.getViewport(ratio);
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;


        // draw the page into the canvas
        var pageTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
        timestamp = pageTimestamp;
        var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: ctx,
                viewport: viewport,
                continueCallback: function(cont) {
                    if(timestamp != pageTimestamp) {
                        return;
                    }
                    cont();
                }
        };
        page.render(renderContext);


        // update page numbers
        document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
        document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;
    });
}
```

Tell me if it's ok now

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a charm. You are a lifesaver. Appreciate it. :)